# How can I show all the results in case of a draw in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

So, I am using PostgreSQL DBMS and I have the following query:

```
Select "CustomerID",Sum("TotalDue") as Total
from "Bike Business"."SalesOrderHeader" 
group by "CustomerID"
order by Total desc limit 1;
```

This query prints the ID of the person with the max cost of orders and the number of the max cost. But in a case of a draw, where 2 or more people have the same max cost of orders, I want the query to print their IDs and max cost also. How can I do that?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run then they are worth it.

Comment: Oh, didnt know that..How should I use identifiers then? Cause postgre keeps giving me errors when i use identifiers without quotes

Comment: Never use double quotes. Don't use them when you create the tables, so you don't need to use them later (and it's Postgres, not Postgre)

Comment: Ι created the tables automatically from the programm, not by code, thats why the tables were created with quotes. And you are right, postgres. Thanks for everything man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions for that:

```
select "CustomerID", total
from (
  Select "CustomerID",
          Sum("TotalDue") as Total,
          dense_rank() over (order by Sum("TotalDue") desc) as rnk
  from "Bike Business"."SalesOrderHeader" 
  group by "CustomerID"
) t
where rnk = 1;
```

This is probably going to be faster then an equivalent query with a sub-select or derived table.

And it has the additional benefit that you can easily get the 2nd or 3rd highest value as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are looking for the 1 or more customers that have the highest total amount due.

```
WITH customer_total AS
(
SELECT
    CustomerID,
    SUM(TotalDue) as Total
FROM
    "Bike Business".SalesOrderHeader
GROUP BY
    CustomerID
)

SELECT
    CustomerID,
    Total
FROM
    customer_total
WHERE
    Total = (SELECT MAX(Total) FROM customer_total);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case determine the maximum due amount in a subquery and join it back to your query without a limit:

```
Select CustomerID,Sum(TotalDue) as Total
from "Bike Business"."SalesOrderHeader"
join
    (Select Sum(TotalDue) as MaxTotal
     from "Bike Business"."SalesOrderHeader"
     group by CustomerID
     order by Total desc
     limit 1) t1
group by CustomerID
having Total=t1.MaxTotal
```

Comment: Thanks man, but how can I join it? How is the correct way to write this in Postgre sql code?

Comment: @NikosLardas since the bigger part of my answer is an actual sql query, I'm completely at a loss as to how to interpet your question...

Comment: If it works, then you can mark the answer as accepted, so other viewers of the topic will know that the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Will do, have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries

```
 SELECT CustomerID,su FROM ( 
                SELECT CustomerID,sum(val) as su FROM 
                "Bike Business"."SalesOrderHeader"  GROUP By CustomerID) tmp2 
        WHERE su =(SELECT max(tmp.su) FROM( 
                SELECT CustomerID,sum(val) as su FROM 
                "Bike Business"."SalesOrderHeader"  GROUP By CustomerID)tmp);
```